CTA in email overview and in email header
I have now seen this feature multiple times, but I haven't found any information on it anywhere.
In example, when I receive a shipment update from Amazon, I get a CTA button in my Outlook (android) app, where I can directly track the package.
This button is also visible above the header of the email if I open it up.
It seems like it's something that outlook generates itself, because the email is in English, but this button and information is localized.
My assumption is that you somehow can include the information in the content of the email in a format that enables some email clients, like Outlook for Android to generate this additional feature.
Does anyone have information on how it's generated?


I am not sure how this works in Outlook, but Gmail has been using schema markup for presenting this type of annotations for a couple of years. You can read about it here and here. Whether Outlook utilises same schema, or if they automatically fetch the content based on the text in email, I don't know. What you should be aware of, is the fact that Gmail's support of this schema seems to be... degraded... as per this thread.

Thanks for the links, that was exactly what I was looking for!
I was clearly not searching for the right terms
